# SSJS Functions in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

I am trying to create a Data Extension using SSJS Script through Automation Studio.

My script is as follows:

```js
  <script runat="server">
   platform.load("core","1.1");
   var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
        "Name" : "My Demo DE",
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
          { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 },
        ]
    };

    var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
 </script>
```

But it keeps giving me an error when I run the automation, even if I only have the  `platform.load("Core","1.1")` line in my script it still shows error :( ..

is that possible to create DE using script through Automation Studio?

If so why platform.load("Core","1.1") is not working for me? Do I need to do anything extra to enable these functions?

Or is there any other way to run this script on a landing page, if so can someone advice me how to do this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Platform.Load` (used to load the core library) is case sensitive. You will need to use `Platform.Load` instead of `platform.load`.

Also, I would recommend removing the comma after the Field 3 object in your array. It will work if you include it, but it's not strictly valid.

The following code works. However, note that the script will fail if a DE already exists with the same name and external key.

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1");
var deObj = {
    "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
    "Name" : "My Demo DE",
    "Fields" : [
      { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
      { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
      { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 }
    ]
 };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
</script>
```