# How do i create a Data Extension using SSJS in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I need to create a data extension using SSJS in SFMC.

```
<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="Post" executioncontextname=test>
var deObj = {
        "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
        "Name" : "My_Demo_DE",
        "Fields" : [
          { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
          { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
          { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 },
        ]
    };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
</script>
```

I used tis code in automation and ran the automation.The automation runs successfully but i cannot find the Data Extension.Please help out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSJS Functions in Automation Studio](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226158/ssjs-functions-in-automation-studio)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems it is a problem of lacking "Platform.Load" and the unnecessary code in the first line.

Please use the code below:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1");
var deObj = {
    "CustomerKey" : "demoDE",
    "Name" : "My Demo DE",
    "Fields" : [
      { "Name" : "Field 1", "FieldType" : "Number", "IsPrimaryKey" : true, "IsRequired" : true },
      { "Name" : "Field 2", "FieldType" : "Text", "MaxLength" : 50 },
      { "Name" : "Field 3", "FieldType" : "Date", "Ordinal" : 2 }
    ]
 };

var myDE = DataExtension.Add(deObj);
</script>
```

[Source](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226158/ssjs-functions-in-automation-studio)